# Copy and transpose values from a different spreadsheet applying vlookup and adding a new column if necessary

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup, transpose

I have 2 workbooks: WB1 which has a spreadsheet (Sheet5) and data i'd like to extract in range C5:D10000. In C5 there are product codes, in column D there are lot numbers i.e. 001, 002, 003, etc for each product code and in G there are number of products ordered

Example (WB1 - Sheet5):

```
.....C -  D - G    
5 - E1 - 001 - 23    
6 - E2 - 001 - 32    
7 - E1 - 002 - 42    
8 - E1 - 003 - 01    
9 - E2 - 002 - 4
```

And so on

On the other hand, what I want to do in WB2 is this with a macro

```
.......A...... - B... - C... - D... - E    
1 - Code - 001 - 002 - 003 - 004    
2 - E1..... - 23.. - 32... - 01    
3 - E2..... - 32... - 4
```

But I can't imagine a way to do it. I imagine a similar function like VLOOKUP which would take every E1-and-E2 D and G values in a matrix and then transpose G column and paste it in B2-C2-D2 but in the same row as their code

Any ideas would help. Thank you in advance, I know it's a complex question

Comment: Maybe you could place a formula such as `=SUMIFS('Sheet5'!$C:$C,$A2,'Sheet5'!$D:$D,B$1)` into cell B2 (in WB2), and then copy it to other cells in WB2?  Other than that, all I could suggest is use VBA and, if you have problems, post your problematic code so that we can assist you further.

Comment: @YowE3K I believe you are missing the column to sum: `=SUMIFS('Sheet5'!$G:$G,'Sheet5'!$C:$C,$A2,'Sheet5'!$D:$D,B$1)`

Comment: @ScottCraner - thanks - I was playing with `CountIfs` too much yesterday, and my brain is still stuck on the parameters for it.  @Gonzalo - please ignore my formula and consider using Scott's.

Comment: Hey thank you so both so much @yowE3K and Scott, it was so easy I feel stupid for not having thought of it. I don't know why i can't vote for any of your answers but thanks anyways

Comment: You couldn't vote for our "answers" because they were only comments.  I have added a real "answer" now, which you can "tick" as the "accepted answer" (and vote for if you like).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Scott Craner's correction of my comment, you can solve this issue using a formula of

```
=SUMIFS('Sheet5'!$G:$G,'Sheet5'!$C:$C,$A2,'Sheet5'!$D:$D,B$1‌​)
```

Place that formula in cell `B2` of WB2 and copy it to the other cells.